# Ansible - Create multiple mysql users with multiple hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm having the following example variables:

```
applications:
   app1:
     app_user: app1
     db_user: db_app1
     db_pass: abc123
     hosts:
       - 10.0.0.25
       - localhost
       - 127.0.0.1
   app2:
     app_user: app2
     db_user: db_app2
     db_pass: abc345
     hosts:
       - 10.0.0.26
       - localhost
       - 127.0.0.1
```

Now I want to create the users with the mysql_users module (with db_user/db_pass/hosts).

Right now I've no clue how to parse the applications dictionary and handover db_user/db_pass and additionally repeat for each host in applications.app*.hosts

In principle I would need the following list to be generated automatically:

```
- { user: "db_app1", password: "abc123" , host: "10.0.0.25" }
- { user: "db_app1", password: "abc123" , host: "localhost" }
- { user: "db_app1", password: "abc123" , host: "127.0.0.1" }
- { user: "db_app2", password: "abc345" , host: "10.0.0.26" }
- { user: "db_app2", password: "abc345" , host: "localhost" }
- { user: "db_app2", password: "abc345" , host: "127.0.0.1" }
```

Any hints to solve the puzzle would be very much appreciated.

Thx in advance

Comment: If you are asking how to then use the data to create mysql users, one way would be to use the [community mysql module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html)  You could also essentially use the ansible shell command to connect to each database using /usr/bin/mysql -u root .... etc. and use input redirection.  The community module requires some things to handle authentication of the root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *dict2items* to convert the dictionary to a list and iterate with [*subelements*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-lookup-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "user: {{ user }} password: {{ pswd }} host: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ applications|dict2items|subelements('value.hosts') }}"
      vars:
        user: "{{ item.0.value.db_user }}"
        pswd: "{{ item.0.value.db_pass }}"
```

gives abridged

```yaml
  msg: 'user: db_app1 password: abc123 host: 10.0.0.25'
  msg: 'user: db_app1 password: abc123 host: localhost'
  msg: 'user: db_app1 password: abc123 host: 127.0.0.1'
  msg: 'user: db_app2 password: abc345 host: 10.0.0.26'
  msg: 'user: db_app2 password: abc345 host: localhost'
  msg: 'user: db_app2 password: abc345 host: 127.0.0.1'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    applications:
      app1:
        app_user: app1
        db_user: db_app1
        db_pass: abc123
        hosts:
          - 10.0.0.25
          - localhost
          - 127.0.0.1
      app2:
        app_user: app2
        db_user: db_app2
        db_pass: abc345
        hosts:
          - 10.0.0.26
          - localhost
          - 127.0.0.1

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "user: {{ user }} password: {{ pswd }} host: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ applications|dict2items|subelements('value.hosts') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      vars:
        user: "{{ item.0.value.db_user }}"
        pswd: "{{ item.0.value.db_pass }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really a nice way to achive exactly what I wanted to do.